# Hadoop CombineFileInputFormatInput

Tags: hadoop

While using the CombineFileInputFormatInput in inputformat i got error InstantiationException.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://master:54310");

Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(CombineFileInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/hduser/CombineFileInputFormatInput"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/hduser/CombineFileInputFormatOutputNew2"));

System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: Can you get us the stacktrace of this exception?

Answer (score 2):

`CombineFileInputFormat` is an abstract class, you must extend it and implement the createRecordReader method:

```
/**
 * This is not implemented yet. 
 */
public abstract RecordReader<K, V> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
  TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException;
```

Then replace the `job.setInputFormatClass(..)` call with the name of you extended class.